# Can you put a string into an array using something other than .push?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I am trying to do Is i have to get domain results from google images. I am using a GM_xmlhttpRequest to get the info then lopping thru them and putting into an array using .push().
The problam I am having is that I have to count the number of results and if it is under a set amount I have to do another search and so on. So using .push to add the items to the array each time it adds one it triggers my if statement.

```
       GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method:   "GET",
            url:      link,
            onload: function(r) {
                var gurl=[];
                for (i=0; i<10; i++){
                    gurl.push($(r.responseText).find('div.nJGrxf.FnqxG').eq(i).text());
                    let editedList = [...new Set(gurl)];    
                }
                  if (editedList.length < 10){
                    window.open(nextSearch)
                    }
            }
        });`
```

I been trying for hours to find a better method of doing this, any help would be greatly appericated.

Comment: What is the problem with this method?

Comment: yes you can, but it would probably not what you want here. can you explain more?

Comment: every time it adds the url to the array it changes the length, so bascally the code above will open 10 new windows. I tried wrapping the if statment in a setTimeOut function hoping to just get the final length but that did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the following line using the ES6 spread operator

```
gurl = [...$(r.responseText).find('div.nJGrxf.FnqxG').eq(i).text()]
```